# Adding and Couting items in a list

Tags: c#, list, count, addition

Let's say I have a file that looks like this:

```
R34     128590    -74.498   109.728  0    0805_7  
R33     128590    -74.498   112.014  0    0805_7  
R15     128588    -68.910   127.254  0    0805_7  
R32     128587    -65.354   115.189  0    0805_7  
R35     128587    -65.354   117.348  0    0805_7  
R38     128590    -65.354   119.507  0    0805_7
```

What I want to do is add the **2nd column** to a list and have a counter count how many times that item occurs and outputs it with the number and then the counted amount of that number.

Is there a way to do this using a List? If so, how could I go about doing that?

I have tried messing around with things and this is where I was heading.. but it does not work properly

```
int lineCount = 1;
int itemCounter = 0;

foreach (var item in aListBox.Items)
{
    // Creates a string of the items in the ListBox.
    var newItems = item.ToString();

    // Replaces any multiple spaces (tabs) with a single space.
    newItems = Regex.Replace(newItems, @"\s+", " ");

    // Splits each line by spaces.
    var eachItem = newItems.Split(' ');

    ### 
    ### HERE is where I need help ###
    ### 
    List<string> partList = new List<string>();

    partList.Add(eachItem[1]);
    if (partList.Contains(eachItem[1]))
        itemCounter++;
    else 
        partList.Add(eachItem[1]);

    sw.WriteLine(lineCount + ": "+ partList + ": " + itemCounter);
    lineCount++;
}
```

***SO*** for the example above, it would output this:

```
1: 128590: 3        #lineCount, partList, itemCounter
2: 128588: 1
3: 128587: 2
```

Can someone help me figuring out how to properly do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either use a Linq query or a Dictionary

something like

```
    List<string> items = new List<string>{"128590", "128590", "128588", "128587", "128587", "128590"};
    Dictionary<string,int> result = new Dictionary<string,int>();

    foreach( int item in items )
    {
        if(result.ContainsKey(item) )
            result[item]++;
        else
            result.Add(item,1);
    }

    foreach( var item in result )
        Console.Out.WriteLine( item.Key + ":" + item.Value );
```

Answer (score 4):

use [linq with count and group by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747) (see Count- Grouped section).

create your `partList` outside the foreach loop and add each item to it inside the loop , so that it would contain all of the elements:

```
List<string> partList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in aListBox.Items)
{
    //regex stuff here...
    partList.Add(eachItem[1]);
}
```

(in your example- `{128590, 128590, 128588, 128587, 128587, 128590}`)
and then use LINQ to output the result-

```
var elementsWithCounts = from p in partList
     group p by p into g
     select new { Item = g.Key, Count = g.Count()};
```

Comment: @sJhonny: I tried this and it has a problem with the *group by* section

Comment: @theNoobGuy- firstly, I didn't test this so it's bound not to be perfect (sorry..). my idea was for you to get the concept; have you looked at the examples I've provided? have you got the general idea? also, I'd be happy to help you but you need to be more specific than 'it has a problem': what's the error message / exception..?

Comment: sorry, should have been `group p by p`; I've edited my answer. should be OK now.

Comment: @sJhonny: How would I output the data once it is in that form? Sorry I am unfamiliar with LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the items split by space, I'm assuming you have a string array looking like so:

```
[0] = "R34"
[1] = "128590"
[2] = "-74.498"
[3] = "109.728"
[4] = "0"
[5] = "0805_7"
```

You can simply perform this operation with a Group By operation.

```
var items = aListBox.Items.Select(x => /* Split Code Here and Take Element 1 */).GroupBy(x => x);

foreach(var set in items)
{
     Console.WriteLine(set.Key + " appeared " + set.Count() + " times.");
}
```

Comment: So would I just add my code into the Split code here and take element 1 section?

Comment: Pretty much. They key here is the `GroupBy()` method though.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are trying to do this by iterating once, and that is not really going to work, you are going to have to iterate twice, otherwise you will wind up doing an output every time you loop in the foreach, and even if your accurate you are going to be outputting a new line each time.  If you need to really use a List instead of a keyed dictionary or hashtable which would be idea for this (key = number, value = count), then you need to build the list first, then summarize the list.   You can either use LINQ Group By (which is a bit terse), or create a function that does something similar to what you already have.   If you are trying to learn concepts, look at the code below, it could be more condensed but this should be fairly easy to read.

```
List<string> partList = new List<string>();
List<string> displayedNumbers = new List<int>();

// Build the original list first.
foreach (var item in aListBox.Items)
{
    // Creates a string of the items in the ListBox.
    var newItems = item.ToString();

    // Replaces any multiple spaces (tabs) with a single space.
    newItems = Regex.Replace(newItems, @"\s+", " ");

    // Splits each line by spaces.
    var eachItem = newItems.Split(' ');

    partList.Add(eachItem[1]);
}

// Now run through that list and count how many times the same number occurs.
// You will need two loops for this since your list is a single dimension collection.
foreach(var number in partList)
{
  var innerList = partList;


  // set this to zero because we are going to find at least 1 duplicate.
  var count = 0;

  foreach(var additionalNumber in innerList)
  {
    if(additionalNumber == number)
     {
       // If we find anymore increase the count each time.
       count += 1;
     }
  }  

   // Now we have the full count of duplicates of the outer number in the list.
   // If it has NOT been displayed, display it.
   if(!displayedNumbers.Contains(number))
    { 
      sw.WriteLine(partList + ": " + count);
      displayedNumbers.Add(number);
    }

}
```

Comment: I like this. One problem with this is that if it reaches the same item it will reprint it again.. meaning if the data looked like this: ***1: 128590: 3\n 2: 128590: 3\n 3: 128588: 1\n 4: 128587: 2\n 5: 128587: 2\n 6: 128590: 3*** instead of not outputting the eachItem[1] only 1 time

Comment: Ha, true, sorry I didn't test it, just banged it out in the web editor.

Comment: Do you know what you would do to change it so it only does it once?

Comment: Sorry, yeah I edited it to handle that, basically you have to keep track of what has been displayed.  Again, a key/value collection like a hashtable or dictionary would be a lot cleaner, but if the requirement is for a list this is how you would have to accomplish it.

Comment: Oh I see.. This still does not seem to be working properly :(. It says there are some invalid arguments for the best overloaded method match

Comment: Sorry had to get to a compiler so I could see the error, edited again, i gotta stop posting untested code on SO =)

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash table instead ofa list. You can save the key as  128590,... and the value the number of times it has occurred. 
Before you insert the new value check if it is already present in the hashtable by using the **Contains** operation and if it is increment the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest problem is getting from raw lines of your text field to individual values. My guess is this is a tab-delimited file with a known constant number of columns, in which case you could use String.Split() to separate the sub-strings. Once you have the strings separated, you can count the instances of the proper column pretty easily with a little LINQ. Given a list or collection of your file's lines:

```
var histogram = myListOfLines
    //Split each string along spaces or tabs, and discard any zero-length strings
    //caused by multiple adjacent delimiters.
   .Select(s=>s.Split(new[]{'\t',' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    //Optional; turn the array of strings produced by Split() into an anonymous type
   .Select(a=>new{Col1=a[0], Col2=a[1], Col3=a[2], Col4=a[3], Col5=a[4]})
    //Group based on the values of the second column.
   .GroupBy(x=>x.Col2)
    //Then, out of the grouped collection, get the count for each unique value of Col2.
   .Select(gx=>new{gx.Key, gx.Count()});
```